# "Shrink to page" SVG on printing?

Tags: javascript, css, svg, media-queries

Is there any way to shrink my SVG graphic to fit the printing page, while leaving the web version of the graphic as it is? Or am I wasting my time?

I can only use FF at the moment but of course a cross-browser approach is even better...

1. Is there a CSS version of viewBox that I can put in a media
   query?
2. Is there an onPrint event in js where I could apply
   viewBox?
3. Any other approach - javascript, css, jquery, d3 all
   welcome.

Googling suggests "no" to 1 & 2 but many of the posts are old.

Latest approach:

```
var svg = d3.select("div#matrix").append("svg")
    .attr("width", 1000)
    .attr("height", 1000)
    //.attr("viewBox","0 0 500 500") - I don't want to apply this to the webpage SVG - this is just for testing
    //.attr("preserveAspectRatio","xMinYMin meet")
    .attr("id","matrixSVG")
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
```

Once the text labels are added to the graphic I resize the container elements for the webpage:

```
var svgWidth = margin.left+margin.right+(cellSize*horizNodes.length);
var svgHeight = margin.top+margin.bottom+(cellSize*vertNodes.length);
d3.select("svg#matrixSVG").attr("width",svgWidth).attr("height",svgHeight);
d3.select("div#matrix").style("width",svgWidth+"px").style("height",svgHeight+"px");
```

CSS:

```
@media print {

  svg#matrixSVG {
    width: 175mm; //this is the max size to fit US letter and A4
    height: 245mm;
  }

 }
```

Thanks for any help